# Como tratar um "redirect" depois de uma chamada Ajax com JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, redirecionamento-de-url

Uso JQuery para fazer uma chamada Ajax (GET). Quando ocorre "redirect", código 302, para uma resposta válida o JQuery retorna erro em vez de redirecionar para a nova URL.
Tem alguma outra forma de tratar isso?

Comment: Isso acontece quando a sessão expira e redireciona para o login?

Comment: @RafaelMarcos no meu caso não é um login, mas o conteúdo responde com código **302** Movido Temporariamente, acho que é isso que está dando o problema para fazer o tratamento.

Comment: O browser deveria tratar do redirect automaticamente... Isso não está ocorrendo? Ou o problema é na hora de tratar **a resposta** do redirect? Experimente usar um `get` simples (sem especificar o formato) e usar o callback `then` (ou `complete`, se for uma versão antiga do jQuery) e veja o que acontece.

Comment: O simples fato de redirecionar com status 302 não deveria dar erro, a não ser que vc tente acessar algo que esteja em formato diferente.

Comment: Descobri que precisava definir a variável **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"** no cabeçalho de resposta do meu servidor web, mesmo com o status 302 funcionou agora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No meu caso, quando redireciono para o login no asp.net, eu adiciono o seguinte cabeçalho na resposta da pagina de login:

```
Response.AddHeader("LOGIN", "LOGIN");
```

Na chamada Javascript, faço o seguinte tratamento:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Pagina.aspx',
        data: dados,
        complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {

            if (XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader('LOGIN') != null)
                window.location.reload(); // Atualizo a pagina para redirecionar para o login

//Seu código

          }
    });
```

Desta forma, o Ajax sabe quando a página solicitada foi redirecionada para o login, quando a sessão expirar.

Comment: Saquei! Você envenena o cabeçalho de resposta com a variável LOGIN.

Comment: Apenas adiciona uma informação, para facilitar o Ajax.

Answer (score 2):

O ajax no jQuery tem 3 calbacks que podem ser usados para o que você quer **complete**, **success** e **error**, você poderia usar tanto o **complete** quanto o **error** para fazer essa verificação.
Veja o exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
    complete: function(data){
        // aqui você manipula os dados para agir de acordo com a resposta do ajax
    },
    success: function(data){
        // aqui você manipula os dados para agir de acordo com a resposta do ajax
    },
    error: function(data){
        // aqui você manipula os dados para agir de acordo com a resposta do ajax
    }
})
```

Todas as outras dúvidas podem ser consultadas na documentação http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/